# How To Detect Clicked div text with same ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#peoplelayer').click(function(){
        $("#peoplelayer").each(function(){

            $("#peoplelayer").fadeOut(500);
            var str = $(this).text();
            alert(str);
            //$("#peoplelayer").fadeTo(500,0.6);

            });

    });
});
```

This is code where i use the same id "#peoplelayer" to all the divs, and when i click on    one of them, it alerts all the texts of this div with the same id

how can i defend this problem, as i need to alert only the clicked div, in addition to that i need to give this divs the same id ???

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Look into using classes instead.

Comment: Your markup is invalid, therefore your code's behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IDs are unique, so you cannot have two elements with the same IDs.  Perhaps you meant to use classes?

Change `id = 'peoplelayer'` on your **divs** to `class = 'peoplelayer'` and you can use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.peoplelayer').click(function(){
        $(this).each(function(){

            $(this).fadeOut(500);
            var str = $(this).text();
            alert(str);
            //$(".peoplelayer").fadeTo(500,0.6); (I know it's commented, but just in case)
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have as images with the same class name as you want. But you can only have one image with a given `id` on your page. The id is unique for the element.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is change them to classes.

So instead of `id="peoplelayer"`, change to `class="peoplelayer"`, and then you could write it like this. I made some changes, I think this would work how you want.

```
$('.peoplelayer').click(function(){
        var str = $(this).text();
        $('.peoplelayer').fadeTo(500,0.6);
        $(this).fadeOut(500);
        alert(str);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the each within the event handler (along with using ids where you should be using classes).  Change the elements to have `class="peoplelayer` and then you can simply write:

```
$(".peoplelayer").click(function(){
    var str = $(this).text();
    $(".peoplelayer").fadeOut(500);
    alert(str);
});
```

The click function will attach the same click handler to each of the elements with a class of `peoplelayer`, so the `each` you were doing within the click handler was unnecessary and caused the text of every element to be displayed each time any of the elements were clicked.

Answer (score 0):

well, u can use classes and use js on them. 
But you can select divs of same id as `$("div[id='peoplelayer']")`.
P.S. giving same id to two elements is not a good practice.
an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac7xp/)